# Site does not work properly on 3G but works on wifi

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, wifi, 3g

We have an web application. When we try to access the site using wifi connection the site loads perfectly but when we try it with the cellular data (3G), it opens the site but some of the elements are not loaded.

So we tried doing some testing.
It turns out if you load the page first time using wifi then it will start loading afterwards on 3G as well until you clear cache and cookies. Wifi connection and 3G have same bandwidth and ping.

Our web app uses lot of javascripts and ajax calls to retrieve data. We added cache: false in every ajax calls to prevent caching. When that didnt seemed to work I added timestamp to the url as well which also failed to solve the problem.

The issue seemed to be related cookies somehow because once cookies are set the web app works fine.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Could it be that some of your asynchronous calls get returned too late? Do you get any errors on 3g?

Comment: We don't get any error but the some of the elements which are retrieved from ajax call are not loaded. Since the ping time of wifi and 3G is same then timeout should not be an issue.

Comment: Also note that once cookies are set on wifi, the site starts working on cellular data as well